# How to loop over multiple elements in an array at a time

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to loop over 10 elements within a big array and see if there are any mismatches with another array (let's call it array2).

```
Dim j As Long, i As Long, arr As Variant

mismatch = Compare_array(array1, array2)    'Compare_array is a function and returns an array of mismatches

For i =LBound(mismatch) to UBound(mismatch)
    j=0
    For arr = mismatch(j + 1, 1) To mismatch(j + 10, 1)
         'other code'
    Next
Next
```

Basically what I want to do is get 10 elements of the mismatch array and perform other procedures with it. After the other procedures are done, I want to take the next 10 elements of the mismatch array, and so on. I'm just not sure if I have done the second for statement correctly.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, all you should need to do is step through the array by 10s, then have the inner loop offset the main index:

```
For i = LBound(mismatch) To UBound(mismatch) - 10 Step 10
    For j = 0 To 9
        arr = mismatch(i + j)
         'other code'
    Next
Next
```

If you don't have the requirement that the sub-groups have exactly 10 elements, you can add a separate bound calculation to the inner loop by looping through the maximum of elements or however many are left:

```
For i = LBound(mismatch) To UBound(mismatch) Step 10
    Dim innerBound As Long

    If i + 10 > UBound(mismatch) Then
        innerBound = UBound(mismatch) - i
    Else
        innerBound = 9
    End If
    For j = 0 To innerBound
        arr = mismatch(i + j)
        'other code
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Thank you.  I assume this code takes all the ten elements, and not every 10th element in the mismatch array? What does the `- 10` do in the first line?
Also, what if I want the mismatch elements that aren't divisible by 10 to do the same as those that are divisible by 10?

Comment: @user112947 - Yes, it will traverse each element, not every 10th. The -10 makes sure that the inner loop doesn't run past the array bound, because the inner loop is adding an offset to it. What to do with the extra `x` elements if it isn't evenly divisible would depend on what your use requirement dictates.

Comment: Does this mean I can put the same code I put under 'other code' for the extra x elements if it isn't evenly divisible?

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate it.